# Контроллеры домена

Tags: active-directory, dns, windows-server

Добрый деньИмеются 3 контроллера домена(1 физический - 01) и 2 виртуальных (03,04). На 01 установлен Windows Server 2003 R2 на 03 и на 04 Windows Server 2008 R2.Уровень леса и доменов Windows Server 2003.Имеется также member сервер с Windows Server 2008 R2.Суть проблемы следующаяПри выключении 01 member после перезагрузкии не может долго попасть в домен, сначала долго висит на Applying computer settings потом точно также долго на Applying user settings. После входа  в систему он не может резолвить имена в SID. вместо всех учеток в группе локальные администраторы видны SID а не имена.Прошу помочь

Comment: 1. А что в логах в этот момент?2. Какие-либо проблемы сети? DHCP, DNS или потеря пакетов?3. Есть какие-либо "особенные" политики для 01 member?4. Было так всегда или случилось после обновления? Каков вообще статус обновлений?5. Что у вас скажет BITS?> Viewing the BITS job queue:`bitsadmin /list /allusers /verbose`> Cancelling all of the jobs in the queue:`bitsadmin /reset /allusers`> Repairing the BITS service:`bitsadmin /util /repairservice /force`

Comment: А что реплицируется на 03 и 04?

Answer (score 1):

По своему опыту могу сказать, что длительное выполнение Applying computer settings говорит скорее всего о сбоях работы в DNS сервере. Особенно остро этот момент касается Win 2003/XP. Так как, когда win7 не может длительное время получить ответ от AD (по той же причине недоступности DNS), то авторизовываться за пк она позволяет только в том случае, если учётная запись уже закешированна на жёстком диске.